# Add framework to Embed Frameworks Build Phase in XCode iOS 8 project using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods, build-process

I am trying to figure out how use CocoaPods to add a number of frameworks to the Embed Frameworks Build Phase in XCode.  My project uses several vendored frameworks from a private pod repo.  I can pod install and build successfully.  The frameworks are not being added as Embedded Frameworks, so I will get a runtime error when the application runs.  The only way I can fix this is to manually add the frameworks to the build phase manually.

Here is an example pod spec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "ExampleiOS"
    s.version      = "1.0.1"
    s.summary      = "ExampleiOS"
    s.homepage     = "http://www.example.com"
    s.author       = { "Example.com" => "" }
    s.platform     = :ios
    s.source       = { :git => "ssh://git.example.com:1234/pkg/ExampleiOSFramework", :tag => "1.0.1" }

    s.source_files = "ExampleiOS/ExampleiOS.framework/Headers/*.h"
    s.vendored_frameworks = "ExampleiOS/ExampleiOS.framework"
    s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
    s.requires_arc = true
    s.xcconfig  =  { 'LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/ExampleiOS"',
                     'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/ExampleiOS"' }
    s.license = {
        :type => "Copyright",
        :text => <<-LICENSE
            Copyright 2015 Example.com. All rights reserved.
        LICENSE
    }
end
```

Is there a way to modify this so the framework will be added to the Embed Frameworks Build Phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using the the latest beta of CocoaPods.

The fix to the embedded framework problem is listed in [this bug report](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1993).

Hopefully the beta will soon be released.